# Lower and upper bounds for harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-functions, upper-lower-bounds, maximum-principle

Is there any theorems to obtain Lower and upper bounds for harmonic functions on a complex domain that contains a segment of the real line, especially in that segment? I found some old maximum principles such as Giraud's principle, Hopf..etc but I didn't find any good materials on the topic.

Any reference would be helpful.

Comment: I think this question is way too general. What type of bounds do you want, in terms of what kind of data?